# Using ImageMagick in Python/Django application results in permission errors on Linux

Tags: python, linux, django, permissions, imagemagick

I use ImageMagick executables in my Django application and all of them work perfect on Windows machine. However, on a Linux machine, I'm getting errors, when I try to run one specific command:

```
command = ["convert", "input1.tif", "-write", "mpc:red", "+delete", "input2.tif", "-write","mpc:NIR","+delete","(","mpc:NIR","mpc:red","-evaluate-sequence","subtract",")","(","mpc:red","mpc:NIR","-evaluate-sequence","add",")","-evaluate-sequence","divide","-normalize","output.tif"]
subprocess.call(command)
```

This command triggers `convert` utility, which itself produces some cache files (named `red` and `NIR`), but the problem is that for some strange reason `convert` can not create these files and throws such error messages:

```
convert: unable to open image 'red': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.
convert: unable to open image 'NIR': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.
convert: unable to open image 'NIR': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.
convert: unable to open image 'red': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.
```

I should add that on Windows this command works great and does what it should do. And on Linux it also works if I run it in Python shell. The problem pops up, when I call this utility in my Django web application.

Comment: You need to escape the parentheses on Linux with a \ e.g ( ) become \\( \\)

Comment: Thanks, Bonzo! Does it mean, that my command should look like `command=[...,"\(",....,"\),..."`?

Comment: I do not know how Django works but I would guess so.

Comment: I guess it is not Django fault. It has something to do with permissions, because, as I said, if I run it just in the same manner in Python shell, it works good.

Comment: I've just tried `\(` and got this error message: `convert: unable to open image '\('` and this message goes after `convert: unable to open image 'red'`

Comment: Obviously, the first error message comes from `-write mpc:red`. ImageMagick for some reason does not have enough permission to create this red file in a Apache web folder.

Comment: On Unix systems parentheses need to be escaped as \(  and  \). See if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, it helped.However, permission error has not gone away.